# Sed command to search a line and uncomment following lines

Tags: linux, sed

I'm looking for a sed command to edit an `Arch Linux` mirror file. This command should search for a **#** commented country name like **#Germany** and uncomment the following *eight* **#** commented lines.

Any help is appreciated.

Example:

before:

```
#Germany
#hostA
#hostB
...
#hostH
#hostI
...
#hostZ
```

after:

```
#Germany
hostA
hostB
...
hostH
#hostI
...
#hostZ
```

Comment: Please provide a few example input lines from the file together with the desired output.

Comment: Done. Added example as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `GNU sed` you can do something like

```
gsed  '/#Germany/,+4{/#Germany/ n; s/^#//}'
```

---

**Example**

```
$ cat test
Some
random
stuff

#Germany
#1
#2
#3
#4

$ gsed  '/#Germany/,+4{/#Germany/ n; s/^#//}' test
Some
random
stuff

#Germany
1
2
3
4
```

---

**What it does**

- `'/#Germany/,+4` This is an address pattern. It matches the first `#Germany` and 4 lines following it. If it matches, it performs the commands for this pattern
- `/#Germany/ n;` If it is the country name, we may not replace it. `n` stands for next, it reads the next line to the buffer.
- `s/^#//` Replaces `#` with nothing.

Answer (score 2):

similar in `awk`

```
$ awk 'c&&c--{sub(/^#/,"")} /#Germany/{c=8} 1' file
```

Comment: I've chosen the command from *nullp01n73R*, because the question asks about **sed**. Thank you anyway.

Comment: If the question is "How do I drive a nail with a screwdriver?", one does not discount the answer "use a hammer" because the question wasn't about a hammer.